# How do I stop JavaScript element clearing everything on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The first delete produced works fine when clicked on "add more" but `del` element produced after that deletes everything present on the page. Can someone please help me, maybe something is wrong with `ele`, I don't have much experience with JS

Steps to reproduce :

1. Click on add more and then the next add more which got created on click the previous add more.
2. click on the last del
3. It deletes everything rather than deleting that very `DIV`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-copy").on('click', function() {
    var ele = $(this).closest('.example-2').clone(true);
    ele.find('input').val('')
    if (ele.find('button').length<2) {
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.innerHTML = "Delete";
      btn.onclick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        ele.remove()
      }
      ele[0].appendChild(btn);
    }
    $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="card-title">Add Class</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form action="#">
          <div class="example-2 form-group row">
            <!--<label class="col-form-label col-md-2">Input Addons</label>-->
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">Class Name</span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button class="btn-copy btn btn-primary" type="button">Add More</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>


        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you describe how to reproduce the problem exactly?

Comment: click on run code snippet, then click on add more, the first del will work fine but when click on add more again the second del won't work

Comment: Well I'm not seeing a problem or you're not describing it *exactly*. When I click delete it works and there's no delete btn. Then I click on add more and click the one and only delete btn it still works.

Comment: see click add more and thenn again add more and then click on second del

Comment: follow the exact steps

Comment: 1)add more twice

Comment: I did. No problem.

Comment: 2)click on last del

Comment: the second del and after that deletes everthing

Comment: the function of del button is to delte only that specific div but those deletes everything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237013/discussion-between-aazim-khaki-and-wazz).

Comment: check your chat message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the use of `.clone()`

You where cloning the latest cloned element which forced you to create an if statement to prevent creating more than one delete button. But that also did not allow you to execute what was inside the if statement after a certain number of nodes cloned.

You also could not use the btn variable outside that if statement.

The solution is to clone always the first `example-2`element so we can jump the use of the if statement and allow the btn variable to be used freely.

I added an extra div `#wrapper` to use `find('div').first()` so the same `example-2` element can be copied every time.

### Snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-copy").on('click', function() {
    
    var ele = $('#wrapper').find('div').first().clone(true);
    ele.find('input').val('');
    
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Delete";
    ele[0].appendChild(btn);

    btn.onclick = (e) => { ele.remove() };
    $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="example-2 form-group row" style="margin-top:15px">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">Class Name</span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn-copy btn btn-primary" type="button">Add More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-top:30px">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```